# guild.members not working properly in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm tryin to code a Discord bot, and I need to get a list of all the members of a guild. I'm using guild.members for this, but this returns a list with only the bot itself.

Here is the manner I proceed:

```
class MyClient(discord.client):

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("The bot is ready!")

    async def on_message(self, message):

        if message.content.startswith(<name of the command>):
            <code of the command>

        if message.content.startswith(<name of the command>):
            <code of the command>

    async def <event>(self, <parameters>):
        <code>

client = MyClient()
client.run("<token>")
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably happening because you didn't enable [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Intents). Discord restricts you from getting some information by default. To change it:

1. Go to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), choose your app, go to **"Bot"**.
2. Under **"Privileged Gateway Intents"** you will see **"Server Members Intent"** - enable it.
3. Then inside your code add this:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents) #add intents=intents to your client
```

Now you should be able to get a list with other members too.

### Edit:

Change:

```py
client = MyClient()
```

to:

```py
client = MyClient(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I think this is because I'm not using commands from discord.ext. I put above an example of how my code is organized

Comment: I just tested your code and edited my answer. It should work now.

Comment: It worked properly, thank you for your help :). You could even not specify the command_prefix parameter